# Parsing C++ strings

Tags: c++, string, parsing, c++11

There are lots of posts here about posting strings but non actually seems to fit to my purpose.

I'm using `std::string` and all of C++ standard libraries, and I have a text file using the following protocol:

```
TEXT1:TEXT2-TAB-TEXT3:TEXT4 TEXT5
```

When `-TAB-` is `\t`.

I want to get all the text into strings (could be an array too). All of the lines in the file are written this way, I tried using `istringstream` but it has no functionality such as: `iss >> text1 >> ":" >> text2 >> "\t" >> text3 >> ":" >> text4 >> " " >> text5`.

Do I actually need to parse using the basic functions of `find` etc. ? That'd be just a ton of work (because I have a couple of files written in different formats and I'll need to make a general function for all of these), I would do that if I have no choice though.

So... is there any way to parse strings the following ways, using known characters between strings? It's not a specific delimiter because each line contains a couple delimiters (one time it's space, then a colon and so). I want to use C++ standard libraries and not any external library such as Boost.

EDIT:
C++11.

Comment: Which C++ standard can we assume as a minimum? C++11? C++14?

Comment: Is the *order* of the presented delimiters mandatory? I.e, you expect *exactly* a colon, then a tab, then a colon then a space, then the last token? Its doable either way even in a general solution, but that presents a bit more work.

Comment: You can write a helper that will let you write something like `iss >> num1 >> expect('\t') >> num2;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using C++11 and your text lines abide by a protocol, then the tool to use for pattern matching and information extraction are the features found in the regex library.

The pattern to match your protocol may look something like this...

\w+:\w+-\t-\w+:\w+\s\w+

... using the default ECMAScript syntax. There are a few others.

Next, use a raw string literal to initialize a regex object...

regex pat{R("\w+:\w+-\t-\w+:\w+\s\w+")};

So now your code can look like this...

```
#include<regex>
...

regex pat{R("\w+:\w+-\t-\w+:\w+\s\w+")};
smatch m;

while (cin >> str) {  // where str is your line of formatted text
    bool match = regex_search(str, m, pat);
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        cout << m[i].str() << " "; // to make sure each component was matched
    }   
}
```

By the way, *smatch* works like a container and can be iterated so it's very convenient.

**Note**: The above code is not guaranteed to work, it is being used as a guide.

Comment: However, you need to use a very recent compiler and libc++ to get working `<regex>`

Comment: Great answer! It's interesting that regular expressions in C++ are modelled on ecmascript syntax. Also \t being part of the regex syntax. interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a single, fixed character to mark the end of each field, anything like regexes borders on overkill. I'd just use `std::getline` to read each field.

I'd start by defining a struct for the fields in one line, and overloading `operator>>` to read one of those structs:

```
struct line { 
    std::string text1, text2, text3, text4, text5;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) {
        std::getline(is, l.text1, ':');
        std::getline(is, l.text2, '\t');
        std::getline(is, l.text3, ':');
        std::getline(is, l.text4, ' ');
        std::getline(is, l.text5);
        return is;
    }
};
```

With that, you can read a line like:

```
line x;

std::cin >> x;
```

...or, if you have an entire file full of lines like that, you can read them all into a vector, something like:

```
std::ifstream infile("whatever.dat");

std::vector<line> lines {
    std::istream_iterator<line>(lines),
    std::istream_iterator<line>()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should read an entire line using [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) then parse that line, e.g. finding the `'\t'` character using [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) or [find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) method of [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

If possible, switch to [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) at least, since many features of C++11 would enable you to write less code. In particular [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) from `<algorithm>` is helpful when used with an anonymous [lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29).

Of course, you should define more formally the acceptable input (perhaps with some [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) notations, at least in comments). In particular, what *exact* characters can appear in your *`TEXT1`* and *`TEXT2`* and *`TEXT3`* and *`TEXT4`* and   *`TEXT5`*. In what encoding? ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) has multibyte characters!).

If the input specification is complex, you might consider using some [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), etc..

Comment: I'm using C++11.
About the characters, I use normal characters (basic char), and text1 and text3 contain numbers and dots, text2 and text4 contain numbers only and text5 contains regular ABC.

Comment: By char, I meant normal ASCII. But only alphanumeric would show in the file (besides the colons and tabs).

Comment: So you need to specify more formally and more systematically the acceptable inputs! Well specifying a problem is half-way of the solution